# Finding IP address of devices connected through LAN to a router from ESP32 connected through WiFi with the same router

Tags: linux, ip, ethernet, esp32

I have an ESP32 which is connected to a router through WiFi. I have a Linux system which is connected to the same router through a LAN cable. I want to be able to get the IP address of the Linux system from the ESP32 so that I can send data.

I cannot give the Linux a static IP. I also cannot program the router using DD-WRT or Open-WRT. I am looking for something with which I can read the iptables on the router and resolve the IP address of the linux machine using it's hostname. I haven't found anything regarding it yet. I also had an idea to add a small dns srver on the Linux which will attach it's IP to a known hostname which the ESP will know. It will just send the data to that hostname which should be resolved by the dns on the Linux. However, I' not sure what to look for and if the router will forward the data to the dns on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hostByName` function

```
const char* hostname = "thelinuxserver"
IPAddress resultIP;
WiFi.hostByName(hostname, resultIP);
```